# Can I set the height of the header manually? (Header cutting off some of it's own content)

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, headers

I am making a fairly complicated "mail merge" template (using mail merge functionality to accomplish something similar but not exactly the same as mail merge) that has a VERY large first page header, almost a whole page. When I am editing certain items in the header, all of the sudden it will shrink and cut off half of the content in the header and not let me edit anything below the cutoff line.

Is there a way to force a specific height for the header? Dragging the lines on the side ruler doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Yes: Insert / Header & Footer / Header / Edit Header / Position / Header from Top:

But a very large header seems inadvisable (it is a feature where Word has had problems) and *usually* very large headers can be avoided.

Might also be worth checking that there is no conflict with margins or Footer.